# My nested function isn't operating as I would like

Tags: javascript, function

My `makeRows` function isn't working as I would expect, I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way. When I press "clear all" the prompt runs to make new rows and columns but the `mouseOver` class isn't being added back to the whole grid, only the bottom part.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");

function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", rows);
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-cols", cols);
  for (c = 0; c < rows * cols; c++) {
    const cell = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item mouseOver";
  }
}

window.onload = makeRows(16, 16);

const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const div = container.getElementsByTagName("div");

function reset() {
  [].forEach.call(div, function (el) {
    el.classList.remove("mouseOver");
  });
  let num = prompt("How many rows and cols?");
  makeRows(num, num);
}

btn.addEventListener("click", reset);
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}

.mouseOver {
  transition: 0s 10s;
}

.mouseOver:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
  transition: 0s;
}

#btn {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="etch.css" />
  </head>
  <header>
    <button id="btn">Clear All</button>
  </header>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
  <footer>
    <script src="etch-script.js"></script>
  </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want to delete the existing divs when you press the clear all button or just remove the mouseOver-class? Because that is, what you do - remove the mouseOver class.

Comment: I would like to reset the whole grid as if I was making it from scratch. You're saying I need to add something to remove all the divs as well? That makes sense. I didn't think about that.

Comment: yes you do - at the moment you leave the existing divs in place and just remove the mouseOver class and add the new divs - thats why you get that behaviour.

Comment: I see. So I wouldn't even need to remove the class. How would I go about removing all of those divs at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all items with class `grid-item` use this iteration in your reset function:

```
function reset() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item').forEach(e => e.parentNode.removeChild(e));
  let num = prompt("How many rows and cols?");
  makeRows(num, num);
}
```

This selects all elements with class grid-item and for each found div it selects its parent node and removes itself from it.

Comment: Where do I place it? If I add it to ```reset``` it clears the grid but doesn't repopulate.

Comment: updated answer - dont select all divs, just the items with proper class.